# netcat doesn't send final FIN to close the connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, netcat

I am playing with self-made nodejs tcp server and testing its behaviour with netcat under Linux. Upon the establishing the connection the server sends 'Test' string down the line and closes the socket. I expect the netcat to close the connection on its side by sending appropriate tcp packets, but it doesn't!
Here is what I do:

```
nc -v localhost 9000
```

After that the whole conversation looks like this:

```
netcat --> server (SYN)
netcat <-- server (SYN, ACK)
netcat --> server (ACK)
netcat <-- server (PSH, ACK)
netcat --> server (ACK)
netcat <-- server (FIN, ACK)
netcat --> server (ACK)
```

At this point I would expect netcat to send FIN but it never does. Connection hangs in FIN-WAIT-2 on one side and CLOSE-WAIT on the other.

If I try the same thing with telnet:

```
telnet localhost 9000
```

it behaves as expected and terminates the connection after receiving 'Test' string.

**The question is why does netcat behaves differently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netcat` was designed to work until both sides have closed the connection. You still have one side left open.

When the server closes the connection with FIN the connection remains in a half-open state where you can send data and the server can receive it. The connection will remain in this state until you close netcat's stdin (type Ctrl-D), which makes it send a FIN packet to the server.

Comment: Well, it might be a rather new feature in netcat then. I am pretty sure I remember the time when it DID close the connection. I used it to make manual http GET requests, and it did exit after receiving the page html.

Comment: I think I remembered wrong: in all tests I can think of my copy of netcat shuts down when remote side sends FIN. Which netcat do you use, there are several implementations?

Comment: Netcat version 6.45, Fedora 20. Launching from Konsole in KDE. But you were right -- it didn't close the connection after completing an http GET request either -- I've just tried nc www.google.com 80.

Comment: @DmitryS., @Joni, I can confirm: with `nc` on Fedora 25 the connection stays half-open. This is Nmap's Netcat replacement (nmap-ncat-2:7.40-1.fc25). Btw, `socat` (as in `socat stdin TCP4:example.org:80`) shuts down the connection when the server sends a FIN, by default.